# Typescript misunderstanding with ElasticSearch Node Client

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch

Using:

- NodeJS `v16.16.0`
- "@elastic/elasticsearch": "8.7.0",

I want to create a function that will accept multiple kind of bulk operations.
The goal for me is to ensure the input of this functions will affect my index with good values (here `a` or `b`).

Here is the code snippet that i cannot correctly type:

```
import { Client } from "@elastic/elasticsearch";

// Operation 1 affect 1 index with "index" action
interface Op1IndexRow {
  index: {
    _index: string;
    _id: string;
    retry_on_conflict: number;
  }
}

interface Op1BulkDocument {
  a: string,
}

type Op1BulkBody = Array<Op1BulkDocument | Op1IndexRow>;


interface Op2IndexRow {
  index: {
    _index: string;
    _id: string;
    retry_on_conflict: number;
  }
}

interface Op2BulkDocument {
  b: string,
}

type Op2BulkBody = Array<Op2BulkDocument | Op2IndexRow>;

const client = new Client({
  node: 'localhost'
})

const bulkSave = async (operations: Op1BulkBody | Op2BulkBody) => {
  await client.bulk({
    refresh: true,
    operations,
  });
}
```

The thing I really don't understand is that i can make it "typescript friendly" with the following type: `Array<Op1BulkDocument | Op1IndexRow | Op2BulkDocument | Op2IndexRow>`.

The problem is that this type is wrong for me because the operations is either `Op1BulkDocument | Op1IndexRow` either `Op2BulkDocument | Op2IndexRow` but never both at the same time.

Comment: What is _"it"_?

Comment: _"never both at the same time"_. The actual value only has one type. Do you need to do something depending on the actual type in `bulkSave`?

Comment: @rveerd no, i just want to ensure that i pass good values when calling `bulksave`
"it" is the type of "operations" parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided almost does what you want. For example, it does not allow you to mix `Op1BulkDocument` with `Op2BulkDocument`:

```js
declare const op1doc: Op1BulkDocument;
declare const op2doc: Op2BulkDocument;
bulkSave([op1doc, op2doc]);
```

> Argument of type '(Op1BulkDocument | Op2BulkDocument)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Op1BulkBody | Op2BulkBody'.

That is because `Op1BulkDocument` has a member `a` which `Op2BulkDocument` does not have.

However it does allow you to mix `Op1IndexRow` with `Op2IndexRow`:

```js
declare const op1index: Op1IndexRow;
declare const op2index: Op2IndexRow;
bulkSave([op1index, op2index]);
```

Why? The error message already gives you a hint: `Op1IndexRow` en `Op2IndexRow` have the same definition. You can *assign* a variable of type `Op1IndexRow` to a variable op type `Op2IndexRow`, because they have the compatible definitions.

TypeScript does not look at the exact interface name but checks if the interface definition is the compatible (is *assignable*).

I suggest you use a single interface `OpIndexRow` instead of two different (but the same) interfaces.